# What type of undergraduate mechanical engineering project is appreciated in industry?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, new-job, careers

What do industry employers see in the final year project of a fresh mechanical engineering graduate?

And how much importance final year project holds in applying for a job?

For example if I have made a final year project in field of heat transfer, does that really give me an edge over a student who has made project in some other field when applying for a job in lets say heat exchanger industry? Do employers really notice final year projects in our CV?

And I have heard that totally researched based projects like analysis of a system using softwares etc. are good when you are willing to apply for a masters degree later but bad for getting into an industry. I have heard that industry likes projects of a more practical nature? Is this true? And what is exactly projects of practical nature? Any examples?

Comment: Hey Student, and welcome to [workplace.se]. You have a bunch of different questions here that don't really have a single answer (the answers would indicate personal preference) which doesn't fit well with the concept in our [about] or [help]. Any chance you could read through those and [edit] your question to focus on a single problem and a solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How important is the content of our final year project when searching for a job?

I would advise against worrying too much about the nature of your final year project unless there is a specific area you are desperate to get in to. In such a scenario, you might as well try and do a similarly themed final project. Very few people in our engineering company have a background in the type of the work they have ended up doing and, in fact, some people have ended up becoming specialists in the very modules they failed while at university.

### What do industry employers see in our final year projects?

When our company asks about our final year projects, they are interested in whether you are able to think creatively, structure a project, plan your time and either get the result you were looking for or be able to explain why you didn't get the result.